# Android, parse JSON in a Java structure

Tags: java, android, json

I need to transform this JSON I receive from an HTTP server into a JAVA structure that allows me to retrieve every single data, for example the first element of the `freq` list.
How can I do? For HTTP requests I use OkHttpClient.

```html
["
  {
    "cpu": 
      {
        "freq": [3193.068625, 1600.0, 3900.0], 
        "usage": [0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.9, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
        "load": [0.22, 0.18, 0.16]
      },   
        
    "memory": 
      {
        "ram": [15.54, 13.07, 15.9, 2.04, 11.24]
      }, 
      
    "disks": 
      {
        "ssd": [219.1, 13.6, 194.2, 6.6], 
        "hdd": [0.0, 0.0, 0, 100.0]
      }, 
      
   "temps": 
      {
        "core-0": [29.0, 85.0, 105.0], 
        "core-1": [36.0, 85.0, 105.0], 
        "core-2": [35.0, 85.0, 105.0], 
        "core-3": [33.0, 85.0, 105.0]
      } 
   }
"]
```

Comment: You mean reading into a pojo with `String author, type`, a class `Opt` with a class `CPU` with a field `List<Doublle> usage` or such. For XML that would be done with JAXB or fastjackson. For JSON for instance jackson with annotations. One would create the classes by hand.

Comment: Check `Jackson` library out. Here is an useful link: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Having the response as a JSONObject, and knowing the format of response, you may use this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

// ...
   

JSONObject opt = response.getJSONObject("opt");
JSONObject cpu = opt.getJSONObject("cpu");
JSONArray jsonArrayfreq = cpu.getJSONArray("freq");    

// Finally, charge the JSONArray into your own list and process it.
List<Double> myList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArrayfreq.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Double>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Hi, the server has been updated and now it returns me an array like the one posted above, what can I do?

Comment: Did you try to do: JSONObject _ob= new JSONObject(response.get(0))  ?? Then you may use the same code I posted.